# for loop not taking any floating point variables

Tags: c++, for-loop, floating-point

I have this problem, where I can input `"2 10 8"` and it will output `"8"`, but I want to be able to input `"2 -25.2 -38.4"`. This immediately crashes the `for` loop and the program displays `"-25.0"` instead of `"-25.2"`, effectively deleting the number in the decimal place.

Is there anyone that can help?

```cpp
int main() {
    int numVals;

    static_cast<double>(numVals);
    double minVal;
    int i;
    int iteration;
    cin >> iteration;

    for (i = 0; i < iteration; ++i) {
        cin >> numVals;
        numVals = numVals * 10; //program completely ignores this...
        if (i == 0) {
            minVal = numVals;
        }
        else if (numVals < minVal) {
            minVal = numVals;
        }
    }

    cout << fixed << setprecision(1)  << minVal / 10 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `numVals` is an int so you can only read integer values into it. I'm not sure what you think `static_cast<double>(numVals);` does, but it doesn't do anything as used in this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to read `-25.2` to a `numVals` variable of type `int`. It reads `-25` to `numVals`, but then tries to read `.2` next time, which is not a valid integer. When you tried this, the input stream variable `cin` goes to a failure state, and doesn't take any more input.

Change `numVals` from type `int` to `double`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double numVals;
    double minVal;
    int i;
    int iteration;

    cin >> iteration;

    for (i = 0; i < iteration; ++i)
    {
        cin >> numVals;
        numVals = numVals * 10;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            minVal = numVals;
        }
        else if (numVals < minVal)
        {
            minVal = numVals;
        }
    }

    cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << minVal / 10 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```